# Add a task to a Spring TaskExecutor only if the current transaction commits

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, transactions

I'm looking to do some work in an @Transactional method, and then as a result of this trigger an asynchronous method to do some more intensive processing. I was planning on doing that simply by using an ExecutorService or a TaskExecutor and adding a task to it - seems easy enough.

However, this asynchronous method shouldn't be run if the original transaction fails, and it would be nice if the transaction would fail should the TaskExecutor reject the task for some reason.

Right now, the best I can think of is to have a method that does the transactional work, and then on that completing to add the task to the TaskExecutor. However, I wondered if there's a way of telling Spring to add the method to the TaskExecutor when the current transaction commits instead of right now?

Comment: Why not just put the code of your async method after you call all your Transactional methods?

Comment: That's pretty much the plan so far, though putting the async method after the transactional method has committed instead of before. The risk otherwise is that if the commit fails for some reason that the async method is still going to be executed.

Comment: It wont, you can always use a return variable and check...If you have a nested transaction, this wont happen too.

Comment: I'm talking the difference between options 1 and 2 in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/sazzer/2fcf93c8984cc95e8c73

Comment: And I meant something like this : http://pastebin.com/Gfs6JFi8